# Two stones are dropped into a still pond, one after another, causing two concentric circular wavefronts: what is the area between the wavefronts?

Tags: calculus

> Two stones are dropped into a still pond, one after another, causing two concentric circular wavefronts that expand out front the point of disturbance. The wavefronts are 0.4m apart and both travel out at the same speed of 0.2m/s.
>
> Find the area between the wavefronts as a function of the radius of the inner circle.

The answer is: $0.8r\pi + 0.16\pi$  How do they get to this answer?

I've tried using $A=b \times h$ for the center section between the wave fronts subtracting the area of a circle divided by $2$ and I come close but I'm missing something.  Can anyone solve the above for me and tell me how the book comes to its answer?

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly. Also, you should show some effort. What did you try to solve the problem? Lastly, try to post using TeX.

Comment: Question is written as: Two stones are dropped into a still pond, one after another, causing two concentric circular wavefronts that expand out front the point of disturbance. The wavefronts are 0.4m apart and both travel out at the same speed of 0.2m/s.   Asks: Find the area between the wavefronts as a function of the radius of the inner circle.

Comment: Iv tried using A= b x h for the center section between the wave fronts subtracting the area of a circle divided by 2 and i come close but im missing something can anyone solve the above for me and tell me how the book comes to the answer of :[ 0.8rPi + 0.16Pi ]

Answer (score 1):

The area of the inner circle is $\pi r^2\ \text{m}^2$ whereas the area of the outer circle is $\pi (r+0.4)^2\ \text{m}^2$.

So the area between the circles is $\pi(r+0.4)^2-\pi r^2\ \text{m}^2$.